# How to simplify code for get array with subbarray by key

Tags: php, function, default

is there some php function equivalent for this code?

```
$pairs = [['id' => 1, 'pairType' => 2], ['id' => 2, 'pairType' => 2], ['id' => 3,'pairType' => 3]];

$tmp = some_php_function($pairs, 'pairType');
```

And in tmp will be

```
$tmp = [ 2 => [1, 2], 3 => [3]]
```

?

I used this code

```
foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
        $tmp[$pair['pairType']][] = $pair['id'];
    }
```

but i hope that php will be some default function for this. Thanks

Comment: Even if PHP would provide such a function, how do you expect it to guess you need `$pair['id']`? You don't specify `'id'` anywhere in the call  *"some_php_function($pairs, 'pairType')"*. Check the list of PHP [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php). [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) is the closest to what you need but you still need to write the body of the `foreach` structure as the body of the callback.

Comment: This question is more fitting for the [code review community](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt function for this, but you can create your own function using the logic below:

```
$pairs = [['id' => 1, 'pairType' => 2], ['id' => 2, 'pairType' => 2], ['id' => 3, 'pairType' => 3]];

$temp = [];

foreach($pairs as $v)
    {
    if (!isset($temp[$v['pairType']]))
        {
        $temp[$v['pairType']] = [];
        }

    array_push($temp[$v['pairType']], $v['id']);
    }

var_dump($temp);
```